# mssql + pymssql engine with sqlalchemy doesn't take attributes in the connection string

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I am trying to pass the attribute MultiSubnetFailover to the connection string using sqlalchemy engine. While passing parameters to pyodbc is pretty smooth, pymssql refuses to accept any parameters in the connection string.

This fails

```
attributes = "?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+sql+server"

engine = create_engine(
        'mssql+pymssql://' +
        "username" + ':' +
        "password" + '@' +
        "127.0.0.1" + "/" +
        "databaseName" + attributes)
```

with the error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ChaitanyaB/PycharmProjects/Test/TestUpdate.py", line 35, in <module>
    (TblServices.OrganizationId == '72A229D4-186B-4B0E-A98F-7DB5DB3566DB')
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2423, in all
    return list(self)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2571, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2584, in _execute_and_instances
    close_with_result=True)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2575, in _connection_from_session
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 893, in connection
    execution_options=execution_options)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 898, in _connection_for_bind
    engine, execution_options)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 334, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind.contextual_connect()
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2039, in contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2074, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 376, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 713, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 480, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1060, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1057, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 323, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 449, in __init__
    self.connection = self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 607, in __connect
    connection = self.__pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 97, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\ChaitanyaB\NewVirtualEnvironment\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 385, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 578, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:9754)
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'MultiSubnetFailover'
```

while it works if I make the attributes = ""

Also, the same connections string with pyodbc works

```
attributes = "?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+sql+server"

engine = create_engine(
        'mssql+pyodbc://' +
        "username" + ':' +
        "password" + '@' +
        "127.0.0.1" + "/" +
        "databaseName" + attributes)
```

I am wondering if there is a different way to pass a connection attribute when we are using pymssql. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: pymssql does not use ODBC, it interfaces directly with FreeTDS, so it's not surprising that an ODBC connection string will fail to work.

Comment: So how can I send attributes with a pymssql connection?

Comment: You can tweak the behaviour of FreeTDS by using the [freetds.conf](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm#TAB.FREETDS.CONF) file, but I don't see anything in there regarding MultiSubnetFailover. You might try asking the [pymssql discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/pymssql).